# Firestore iOS - Delete function in UITableview

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to delete a document from Firestore that appears as a UITableViewCell on my UITableView using the swipe to delete function.

```
 var sourseArray : [Sourse] = []

 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .delete {
        let sourseItem = sourseArray[indexPath.row]
        Firestore.firestore().collection("sourses").document(sourseItem.documentId).delete(completion: { (error) in
            if let error = error {
                debugPrint("Could not delete thought: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
        })
    }
}
```

When I swipe and hit the "delete" button. This error appears

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'FIRInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Invalid document reference.
>   Document references must have an even number of segments, but sourses
>   has 1'

I adjusted the "rules" of my Firestore database to allow for deleting.

After some research it appears that I'm not referencing the correct document somehow. Is it a bad reference or is the error something else?

Also here is what a "sourse" model is.

```
class Sourse {
    private(set) var name: String!
    private(set) var content: String!
    private(set) var timeStamp: Date!
    private(set) var documentId: String!
    private(set) var userId: String!

    init(name: String, timeStamp: Date, content: String, documentId: String, userId: String) {
        self.name = name
        self.content = content
        self.timeStamp = timeStamp
        self.documentId = documentId
        self.userId = userId
    }
}
```

//EDIT

I just noticed I did not add a documentId when creating a new sourse. As seen below.

```
@IBAction func addSourse(_ sender: Any) {
        Firestore.firestore().collection(SOURSES_REF).addDocument(data: [
            NAME : sourseTextField.text ?? "",
            CONTENT : contentTextField.text ?? "",
            TIMESTAMP : FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
            USERNAME : Auth.auth().currentUser?.displayName ?? "",
            USER_ID : Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid ?? ""

        ]) { (err) in
            if let err = err {
                debugPrint("Error adding document document: \(err)")
            } else {
                self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
            }
        }
    }
```

However, that is also the way it was in my tutorial and it worked fine.

///Edit 2 To show how I am fetching it.

```
 func loadData() {
        db.collection("sourses").getDocuments() { (snapshot, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            } else {
                if let snapshot = snapshot {
                    for document in snapshot.documents {
                        let data = document.data()
                        let name = data["name"] as? String ?? ""
                        let content = data["content"] as? String ?? ""
                        let timeStamp = data["timeStamp"] as? Date ?? Date()
                        let documentId = data["documentId"] as? String ?? ""
                        let userId = data["userId"] as? String ?? ""
                        let newSourse = Sourse(name:name, timeStamp: timeStamp, content:content, documentId: documentId, userId: userId)
                        self.sourseArray.append(newSourse)

                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            self.tableView.reloadData()
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer: The function to swipe to delete was correct the whole time. As Dopapp pointed out, I was incorrectly loading my document.Id.

Comment: What is the value of `sourseItem.documentId` ?

Comment: It's part of the sourse model. From what I've read, your suppose to delete using a documentID. But yes that field is empty in my Firestore database, while all the others are filled. In the tutorial I followed, it worked the same way.

Comment: I'm using it as a way to reference the "sourse" that has to be deleted....I hope

Comment: Can you add *print(sourseItem)* right after *let sourseItem = sourseArray[indexPath.row]*, run the app and copy that object output from the console include that text in your question?

Comment: Just tried it. It's giving me the same error, "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'FIRInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Invalid document reference. Document references must have an even number of segments, but sourses has 1'"

Comment: @exisro, if you have a question, do **not** edit that into an answer. Instead, leave that as a comment or edit your own question.

Comment: Ok, got it, still new to this.

Comment: My answer is about *fetching*, not adding documents. Also, in Swift, constants are not in uppercase with underscores like they are in Java.

Comment: Ok, I've added to show how I am currently fetching.

Comment: @exisro, in your fetching code, `documentId` is assigned to the wrong value. Check out my answer for the right expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the problem is indeed that your `documentId` is wrong, you may be retrieving it incorrectly. Here is a quick example of how to create your object with the right id:

```
collection.addSnapshotListener { (snapshot, error) in
    if let documents = snapshot?.documents {
        for document in documents {
            guard let data = document.data() else { continue }
            let id = document.documentID
            let sourseItem = Sourse(name: data['name'], ...,  documentId: id, ...)
            // use sourseItem
        }
    }
}
```

If you are doing something similar, I would check if the document ids are being swapped between objects. If so, that might suggest an async-related problem.

For your particular case, `loadData()` should look like this:

```
func loadData() {
    db.collection("sourses").getDocuments() { (snapshot, error) in
        if let error = error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        } else {
            if let snapshot = snapshot {
                for document in snapshot.documents {
                    let data = document.data()
                    let name = data["name"] as? String ?? ""
                    let content = data["content"] as? String ?? ""
                    let timeStamp = data["timeStamp"] as? Date ?? Date()
                    let documentId = document.documentID
                    let userId = data["userId"] as? String ?? ""
                    let newSourse = Sourse(name:name, timeStamp: timeStamp, content:content, documentId: documentId, userId: userId)
                    self.sourseArray.append(newSourse)

                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.tableView.reloadData()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```